# Spidering through ams for associate emails

Tags: php, screen-scraping

So I have a client that wants to spider through sites that he is a member of and collect participating members emails.  Is there commercial software that does that, or am I better off writing a screen scraping script?  This is all assuming that this is permitted at the sites in question of course.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there's a login required, I would presume you could use `wget` to download the site, then search through each mirrored page for email addresses.

That, of course, depends on whether the site is "predictable" - ie, not AJAXy.